# displaying static and dynamic data in textview in android

Tags: android

Is their anyway to display static and dynamic data in textview..

here is my textview defining in my xml

```
<TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/Rowtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="Listiems" />.
```

i have to display the text which is their in android:text and the dynamic data next to it.

is their any way?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
String tempString="Your Dynamic text Here";
TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Rowtext);
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tempString);
spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
text.setText(" ");
text.append(spanString);
```

Comment: thnx chirag..  is their anyway i can make the dynamic data bold and display dynamic data in proper alignment?

Comment: thnx chirag:). i have a idea, i dont know whether it's right, just checking with u. how if i define a table layout and define a row with 2 columns. then define my android:text in one column and my dynamic data in other column. can i do this?

Comment: If you want to text in text view then no need to take table layout. Here in this code i add space between your defined text and dynamic text.

Comment: but it will not be aligned and i have to display 8 textviews. so i thought i will keep in table layout. can i do that?

Comment: @user2143817 yes, you can take table layout and aligned them as you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <TextView
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/Rowtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="Listiems" />.

TextView _tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rowtext);
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan( Typeface.BOLD );
SpannableString ss=  new SpannableString("Your Dynamic text");
ss.setSpan( boldSpan, 0, ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
_tv.append(" ");
_tv.append(ss);
```

For styling spannable string. http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

Resulting snapshot

[image]

Comment: thnx raghu.. is their anyway i can make the dynamic data bold?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do that
1) Provide static text in android:text parameter and then append dynamic text from you class

```
android:text="some static String"
textView.append(Some dynamic String");
```

2) OR you can gave both in class file like below

```
  textView.setText(getString(R.string.someString)+"Some dynamic String");
```

Comment: thnx hardik..  is their anyway i can make the dynamic data bold?